# sql date comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date-comparison

I was given a query similar to this

```
select * 
from stuff where stuff.id = 1 
and start_Dt < = todays_date 
and End_Dt > = todays_date
```

I asked the person who gave it to me why the date comparison, the answer was "The start and end dates are necessary to ensure a unique record match"

I'm confused, wouldn't that comparison equate to any date possible?

Comment: Is `stuff.id` the primary key?

Comment: not sure, don't think so

Comment: Answer depends on ur database structure, params of that query and how u validate record being inserted into table. Without such data its hard to answer ur question. As long as start_Dt is lower than EndDt it will give u records that todays date is in their range.

Comment: @StevieG: Not at all. See my answer

Comment: this table looks like a training schedule table and we can say that the user wants currently ongoing training with the id 1(which distinguish the particular training from the set of current trainings   ) not the training scheduled in future or which ended earlier

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I see what you're getting at. Of course, it only works when there is a constraint in place to ensure that the dates for a given id can't overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, that the IDs in your table are not unique, i.e. you can have more than one row with `stuff.id = 1`.
But only one at any given time is active. This is checked with the date comparison: It returns the row with `stuff.id = 1` that is currently valid. This is the row where the start date is in the past (`start_Dt <= todays_date`)  and the end date is in the future (`End_Dt >= todays_date`).

Comment: "This is the row where the start date is in the past ('start_Dt <= todays_date') and the end date is in the future (End_Dt >= todays_date)" --- essentially any date possible then

Comment: What do you mean? You can get the currently valid entry for any date, yes. You don't need to supply today's date. You could supply a date from last year and you would get the entry that was valid back then.

Comment: This is a good answer. Look up "Type 2" slowly changing dimensions, typically used in data warehousing. Likely you have an Id that may occur many times but is only "active" at any given time.

Comment: the query supplied was meant to use todays date. not sure how that date comparison will "ensure a unique record match"

Comment: @Ronn: Please re-read my answer. At any given time, only **one** entry with ID = 1 is valid. This means, you will get at most one row, for any given ID and date. It has nothing to do with todays date (because that changes all the time...). It has to do with specifying a date **at all**. Otherwise, you would get all entries, the ones not valid any more, the one currently valid and the ones valid in the future. With specifying todays date instead of a date last year, you just ensure that the unique match you get is that one that is currently valid, not the one that was valid sometime last year.

Comment: @ronn:check my comment above does it similar to that?

Comment: @SomeOne: no this is a table from the depths of hell, it's a query to find the price of a product based on it's id

Comment: @Ronn: Chill and calm down. This is nothing special. Just think about it: You can only have one price for your product, but it can change over time. This means every price has a start date and end date, i.e. a date when that specific price started to be the price of the product and a date when that specific price was no longer the price of the product. When you wouldn't specify the date to the query, you would get the complete price history for your product. You need to understand, that `stuff.id` is **not** the ID of a specific price, but the ID of your product!

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I'm in my happy place now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To give an example to illustrate daniel-hilgarth's answer, you may have a table containing a rate which changes overtime.

This particular example shows the standard VAT rate in the UK.

```
id  StartEffectiveDate  EndEffectiveDate    Rate
1   01/01/1900 00:00    30/11/2008 23:59    17.5
1   01/12/2008 00:00    31/12/2009 23:59    15.0
1   01/01/2010 00:00    03/01/2011 23:59    17.5
1   04/01/2011 00:00    01/01/2099 00:00    20.0
```

So for todays rate this will return this row

```
id  StartEffectiveDate  EndEffectiveDate    Rate
1   04/01/2011 00:00    01/01/2099 00:00    20.0
```

The advantage of this system is that you can implement this table beforehand. So in Dec 2009, it will use 15.0 Vat, but automatically changes to 17.5 once your computerdate reaches 1st Jan 2010 and then change again once the date reaches 4th Jan 2011.

You can also use it to plan future price increases.